# Why is RouterModule exported in the Angular document example?

Tags: angular

In the documentation for Angular routing it shows a feature module and how to use the `forChild` static function.

In that example, it shows RouterModule being imported and exported by the feature module.

```
import { NgModule }              from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes }  from '@angular/router';

import { CrisisListComponent }   from './crisis-list.component';
// import { HeroListComponent }  from './hero-list.component';  // <-- delete this line
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
    // { path: 'heroes',     component: HeroListComponent }, // <-- delete this line
    { path: '',   redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#remove-duplicate-hero-routes

I don't understand why RouterModule is exported or see in the documentation any reason for this.

Comment: I found a good explanation here: https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#:~:text=A%20routing%20module%20re%2Dexports,not%20have%20its%20own%20declarations%20. (search for `as a convenience` and you directly get to the right place in document)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting a module essentially exports all declarations (directives, components, pipes) defined on this module.

Routing module defines a set of router specific directives:

```
const ROUTER_DIRECTIVES = [RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouterLinkWithHref, RouterLinkActive];
```

They are registered on the RouterModule:

```
@NgModule({declarations: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, exports: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES})
export class RouterModule {
```

If you want to use them inside your module components' templates, you have to import that module into your feature module. However, you can also import `RouterModule` just once into your shared module `AppRoutingModule` and then import this shared module elsewhere without importing `RouterModule`.

Comment: Awesome. That's going to make life easier. Thanks.

Comment: you're welcome :) I write in-depth about Angular [on medium](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi), you might want to check them out